# Magento 2: custom page for downloadable product

Tags: magento2, downloadable

In Magento 2 is it possible to edit the product page only for downloadable products? For example hidden some block or move block in other location.

Answer (score 1):

I try to edit this file:
catalog_product_view_type_downloadable.xml

located in:

/vendor/magento/module-downloadable/view/frontend/layout